# netatalk 3.0 wont start on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, afp, netatalk

Netatalk 3.0 built from sources using

```
./configure --with-init-style=debian --enable-debian
```

On startup i'm having troubles:

```
Aug 09 01:30:11.415825 netatalk[15692] {netatalk.c:162} (N:AFPDaemon): Restarting 'afpd'     (restarts: 363)
Aug 09 01:30:11.415981 netatalk[15692] {netatalk.c:170} (N:AFPDaemon): Restarting 'cnid_metad' (restarts: 363)
Aug 09 01:30:11.416072 netatalk[16436] {netatalk.c:227} (E:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 09 01:30:11.416196 netatalk[16437] {netatalk.c:227} (E:CNID): Fatal error in exec: No such file or directory
Aug 09 01:30:11.416336 netatalk[15692] {netatalk.c:125} (D5:AFPDaemon): Got SIGCHLD event
Aug 09 01:30:11.416356 netatalk[15692] {netatalk.c:130} (I:AFPDaemon): child[16436]: exited 1
Aug 09 01:30:11.416481 netatalk[15692] {netatalk.c:125} (D5:AFPDaemon): Got SIGCHLD event
Aug 09 01:30:11.416499 netatalk[15692] {netatalk.c:130} (I:AFPDaemon): child[16437]: exited 1
```

my apf.conf file is:

```
[Global]
; Global server settings
;hostname = Storage
log file = /var/log/netatalk.log
log level = default:maxdebug
cnid scheme = cdb

[Storage]
path = /share
```